# Can't connect to my apache server from another computer on the network

Tags: apache, ubuntu, server

I installed Apache 2.4.7(Ubuntu) and have all config files set up. My domain name is www.cj1098.com. I can access it on my main computer through localhost and www.cj1098.com but when I try to access it from another computer on the network or an outside network I get an 
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

This makes me think that I'm not allowing the port through or my firewall is blocking it but I've disabled the firewall and allowed my ip through port 80.

I've also edited the default config file under apache2/sites-available to point to www.cj1098.com and given it the correct directory path name for my index.html.

Is there something I'm missing here? I've tried almost every tutorial I can find about 3 Google pages deep, ha.

I suppose I should mention my windows machine has an apache server that is visible outside of the network, but I couldn't get php to install (on windows) so I installed LaMP on Ubuntu. I have the windows apache server turned off and am trying to get the Ubuntu one working.

Edit: I can now see my index.html file from my windows machine(on the network) by typing in the ip address of my ubuntu machine. I can't access it on an outside network yet or by domain name on another computer yet.

Comment: im gonna take a guess that apache is listening to localhost rather than just listen 80. i think ubuntu puts it in ports.conf

Comment: Damn. Was hoping this was it :(
My ports.conf file is just:

Listen 80

and then if it's an ssl module or mod_gnutls.c listen 443.
Everything is default on apache. I haven't changed what ports apache listens to. What a conundrum

Comment: does the dns point to the correct place ? what happens when you ping it for example ?

Comment: when I ping it, I get responses. And it is pointing to my localhost IP as well. 
Edit: Actually when I ping it on my linux machine it shows my localhost ip address, but when I ping it from my windows machine it shows our network's public ip address. I've tried to forward both ports to no avail.

Comment: Some routers don't like you going "out and back in again", I've found in the past. What if you try and access on the internal IP address? You can also modify `/etc/hosts` to set "www.cj1098.com" to a known internal IP address

Comment: I just set in my hosts file my internal IP like this

xxx.xxx.x.xxx          www.cj1098.com

No dice. Still unable to access it from outside the network or on another computer in the network.

Comment: If you get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, it sounds like you can see the server but not having permissions to access it.

Comment: Well I have a2ensite my config file, which should have enabled the site. Then I've got the directory set to point to my index.html. I'm not sure what other permissions I have to set.

Answer (score -1):

Check if your firewall is enabled

```
sudo ufw status
```

If it is enabled, simply disable it and check again

```
sudo ufw disable
```

If that is the case, disable it again and write the exception rules for your firewall

sudo ufw enable